# Limiting ImageMagick Memory Use

Tags: memory, imagemagick

Basically I'm trying to keep the memory use on my Nginx server under a certain amount, both because I'm insane (according to my friends) & I want to save money. However I'm worried ImageMagick may push it over the edge.

I'm using `-limit area 20MiB` and I've also tried `-limit memory 15MiB -limit map 15MiB` but when checking the process (as it runs) through `top -c (with Shift-M)` and `ps aux` it shows it using, sometimes, considerably more memory than I've set in the limits. To give numbers it may be using 35MB or 40MB, instead of the 20MB/30MB I would expect. I wouldn't be bothered for 2MB or 3MB but that's quite a large offset.

I've been told the extra memory may be the ImageMagick's overhead as it loads the interpreter etc, but I'm not super familiar with Unix programs so haven't a clue in that department.

If anyone can explain why this is happening, that would be great. If it's a normal thing, great. I'll just adjust things to take into account the fact that it may use my limit plus a certain amount, but if it isn't and the `-limit` parameter doesn't limit memory to a certain amount, what exactly is the point in having that parameter in ImageMagick?

Again thanks for your help in advance, it's much appreciated, as always.

Comment: No ideas anyone? It's not a major problem, but I'd love it if anyone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

According the documentation ImageMagick is moving all memory operations to mmaped files, so it will start to swap if you have enough disk space, see the manual:
SNIP from manual **-limit**:

> The value for File is in number of files. The Disk limit is in
>   Gigabutes and the values for the other resources are in Megabytes. By
>   default the limits are 768 files, 1024MB memory, 4096MB map, and
>   unlimited disk, but these are adjusted at startup time on platforms
>   that can provide information about available resources. When the limit
>   is reached, ImageMagick will fail in some fashion, or take
>   compensating actions if possible. For example, -limit memory 32 -limit
>   map 64 limits memory When the pixel cache reaches the memory limit it
>   uses memory mapping. When that limit is reached it goes to disk. If
>   disk has a hard limit, the program will fail.

Comment: I've definitely got enough disk space (50GB+) but it still seems to be using over the amount set via the -limit parameter. Sorry about the large delay in commenting too, I'd forgotten I'd asked the question as ImageMagick seems to be behaving itself despite this still being an issue.

Comment: Just try to install from svn, maybe your version is buggy?

Comment: I believe it was related to the system my host was using. I've since moved to a different host where I can install ImageMagik myself and has been working without issue since.

Answer (score 2):

The Limits only affect ImageMagick's pixel cache. The program code and anything the libraries / delegates may do to load or process the images are not influenced by these settings at all.

You don't specify what you're looking at in top, the proper column would obviously be RES or RSIZE. With such small limits as 20MiB, the program and library code will represent a significant fraction of resident set size.

To verify that you're using the right units for your environment variables, use  `identify -list resource` . If the size of the memory pixel cache (MAGICK_MEMORY_LIMIT) is insufficient for an image, an mmap-ed file will be used (MAGICK_MAP_LIMIT) and if that limit is too low, a conventional disk file (MAGICK_DISK_LIMIT) is used instead. If all the limits are too low, ImageMagick will fail immediately with an error such as `cache resources exhausted`, `Memory allocation failed` or `corrupt image`.

Comment: So the additional memory used could indeed be the library itself being loaded into memory, would an extra 10MB be about right? I am looking at RES it usually bumps an extra 8-10MB on top of my set limit so I have just been assuming it is the program overhead & have adjusted my server memory to accommodate it. Thanks for the answer.